# improve TCPDUMP performance while capturing big amount of traffic

Tags: linux, networking, sniffing, tcpdump

so I'm sending to some machine of mine ~2gbps of small packets (around 3.8 million packets per sec).
the machine have a tcpdump process that writes to a file running continuously without any filters.

the thing is that when I check how much traffic the machine receive I see that the limit is around 900mbps.

I could see that the machine is experiencing high CPU load and that packets are dropping by tcpdump (probably can't handle them).
[dropped packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irxyv.png)

I've tried to increase the ring buffer size to max but it didn't help.

**from what I understand tcpdump not able to do multi processing and therefore is limited by the amount of packets that it can capture with 1 Processor/Core.**

my question is if there's any way to improve tcpdump performance or more importantly to distribute processing of a tcpdump instance on more than one core ?

Comment: What is the goal your trying to achieve? Do you need every single packet in the resulting PCAP file or would a sample packet capture work?

Comment: @jvda it's fine by me to have some packet loss but no more than 10 percent. but maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: So, I'm assuming youre trying to write to a PCAP file to gather some insight/statistics or so? What are you trying to achieve except from storing the packet capture?

Comment: @jvda correct, I'm trying to write it to gather insight/statistics. the PCAP files are being parsed and the packets data stored in a DB. I have management mechanisms for all of that. thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful to you, but I once had a similar problem and found that the bottleneck was not the capturing of the packets but rather writing them to a file.
I ended up directly analysing the captured packets using libpcap and only storing the statistics. I managed to handle up to around 5-10Mpps while doing fairly complex analysis (e.g. resolving IP addresses to AS numbers etc).

Comment: @jvda hey, we can't do it because we need to have these pcap files for our stability.